# Multiple Relationships in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel, relationship, pivot-table, laravel-4, query-builder

I have an Event model and a method called getEvents() which gets a list of events from my events table in my database.

Each event will in turn have delegates associated with it, and this is were it becomes complicated.

There are 3 tables, delegate_event (this is a pivot table, that links the delegates to an event based on event_id and delegate_id), delegates (a simple table containing an id field and a contact_id field) and a contacts table which contains information on a list of contacts.

The delegates table uses the contact_id to link to the contacts table and pull through various pieces of information associated with that contact.

I am using Query Builder and the leftJoin method to get most of the information I need for each event but I now need to pull through a list of delegates. http://paste.laravel.com/qSa

I can't work out how to join the contacts associated with delegates that are associated to the event via the delegate_event table.

Can someone help me out here please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a many-to-many table for event-user because multiple events will have multiple users (delegates) associated with it.

Here's what I have:

mtm_event_user: ID, event, user

*events:* id, name (of event)

*users:* id, contact

*contacts:* id, name, address, etc

Here's the query I have, you can modify the SELECT to suit which fields you need.

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN users ON users.contact = contacts.ID
INNER JOIN mtm_event_user AS meu ON meu.user = users.id
WHERE meu.`event` = 1
```

For multiple events, replace WHERE meu.`event` = 1 with ORDER BY meu.`event`